# How to exclude Puppet modules for a few nodes?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, hiera

I have 80 nodes, 78 need to have a specific module, except for 2.

```
[root@puppetmaster puppet]# cat hiera.yaml
:backends:
    - yaml

:hierarchy:
    - environment/%{::environment}/%{::hostname}
    - environment/%{::environment}
    - common

:logger: console

:yaml:
    :datadir: '/etc/puppet/hieradata'
[root@puppetmaster puppet]# cat hieradata/common.yaml
---
classes:
  - ldap
  - motd
  - ntp
  - puppet-conf
[root@puppetmaster puppet]# cat hieradata/environment/tst/tst-01.yaml
---
classes:
  - puppet-update
  - public-keys
[root@puppetmaster puppet]#
```

I want **all** nodes to have the ldap module, except for the tst-01 and tst-02 server.

How do I exclude this module from these 2 servers?

A solution would be to use 80 .yaml-files for all nodes and add "- ldap" to 78 of these .yaml-files, but this seems poor design. It would be cleaner to exclude the modules from the inherited list.

Comment: Would it be acceptable for the `ldap` module to have a parameter which essentially disables it, and set the param for just those two nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that hiera_include will use the classes from all levels (probably uses hiera_array).

This will probably work:

```
[root@puppetmaster puppet]# cat hieradata/common.yaml
---
classes:
  - ldap
  - motd
  - ntp
  - puppet-conf
[root@puppetmaster puppet]# cat hieradata/environment/tst/tst-01.yaml
---
classes:
  - puppet-update
  - public-keys
  - motd
  - ntp
  - puppet-conf
```

In the node-def:

```
class { hiera('classes'): }
```

Downside is that you would have to specify all classes in the host-specific hiera file, if you override the default.

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this in your `nodes.pp`:

```
node default {
  hiera_include('classes')
}

node /^tst-0(1|2)\.example\.com$/ inherits default {
}

node /.*example\.com$/ inherits default {
  include ldap
}
```